# "with" or "against"? -- "Alexander fought ____ every kind of aggression."

Tags: prepositions

> Alexander fought **with/against** every kind of aggression.

Are both *with* and *against* in the above sentence correct?

Comment: This isn't a proofreading request, *I think*.

Answer (score 2):

This is a tricky question. It really depends on who Alexander is and what we mean by *aggression*.

If Alexander refers to the famous general and we are talking about his fierce fighting style, then we'd say:

> Alexander fought **with** every kind of aggression.

Or if *aggression* here refers to various attacks on Alexander's country, which Alexander and his armies attempted to push back on the battlefield, we could say:

> Alexander fought **against** every kind of aggression.

However, if Alexander is a common man who happens to have a drinking problem along with some anger management issues, we might be able to use either preposition:

> Alexander fought with every kind of aggression.
>   Alexander fought against every kind of aggression.

In this case, aggression would be referring to an "inner demon" of sorts, and the fighting refers to a largely mental battle of self-control.

Sometimes, when we are talking about personal struggles, who we tangle or wrangle *against* is also who we tangle or rangle *with*; neither preposition is grammatically wrong. Consider:

> Muhammad Ali fought with Joe Frazier three times.
>   Muhammad Ali fought against Joe Frazier three times.

Neither sentence is wrong, although *against* typically casts a more antagonistic feeling and mood over the sentence.

---

Context is very, very important. I noticed you're fairly new here on ELL. As you ask future questions, try to provide much more of it. Not only will you get better answers, you'll get more upvotes and less close votes on your question. Our [**Details, Please**](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please) post on meta might help you in the future.

Answer (score 1):

They mean different things.
Here, 'fought with' means he was aggressive and 'fought against' means he resisted every sort of aggression.

Comment: Between 'against' and 'with', 'against' seems more *aggressive!*